# Matlab - Easy way to save entire figure/GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, save

I'm looking for an easy way too save the current state of my GUI and be able to load this saved state again. I know there is a video for this (http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/12/10/how-to-save-and-restore-state-of-a-gui-in-matlab/) but somehow it doesn't work on my computer.

I thought of something like this: (I used gcf because I didn't know the "mainhandle" for my entire GUI)

```
%Save Data
currentdata = getappdata(gcf);
uisave('currentdata',date);

%Load Data
[filename,pathname]=uigetfile({'*.mat'},'Select input file');
load([pathname,filename]);
```

The problem with this way is, that the saved Data is opened in a new figure and not the current one from which I chose to open it.

I was also wondering if it is possible to set a folder(which is added to the matlab path) as the deault folder for saving/loading.

Thank you for your help! Klaus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `currentdata` keeps the whole handles of your GUI, including the handle to the GUI's main figure, so when you load it, there will be a new figure opened.

What one did in the mentioned video is: just save the fields/data that you need to be remained/reloaded in later session.

So either you save these specific fields in the GUI's handles and reload them one by one, or you can use the [exchange functions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24669-gui-with-memory-uiremember---uirestore) mentioned in the comment under the video.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there no easier way to configure the uisave or something else than uiremember/uirestore?

Comment: The uiremember/restore also seems to always restore the last state but I want to be able to save different states (some interesting cases) and be able to load each one after the other

Comment: have you read the code of these functions? You can change the part that saves states into `mem_file`, and wrap the code in buttons' CallbackFcn in your GUI, so you can decide which states you want to save/load. They provided the tools so you dont have to rewrite it, but how to use the tools is your job.

Comment: I have tried but I'm relativly new to matlab and therefore dont quite understand it (this is why I hoped it would be possible to modify uisave to my needs). I don't even see where in the code "last_state.mat" is actually saved to any directory. I first thought about adding `Filename=uiputfile('*.mat','Save); mem_file=Filename` but this wouldn't suffice.